# How do I create subplots in Mathematica using LevelScheme?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, levelscheme

Consider the following arbitrary figure generated in MATLAB as an example. The basic idea is that I have a contour plot and I want to showcase selected slices from it in subplots on the right. Is there an equivalent of subplot in mma?

The work around that I have right now is to have just the contour plot with the slices and the arrows and the two slice-plots separately and then put them together in latex. However, I'd like to be able to do this within mma. How do I go about doing this?

An idea that I had is to generate a the contour plot with a full vertical & half horizontal aspect ratio, the two plots with half vertical & half horizontal aspect ratio, and then use `GraphicsGrid` to align them up. But this still gave me the plots as a list, not a composite figure. Is this the only way or is there a nicer, more elegant way of doing it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that `Multipanel` in [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/) can probably let you do what you want - but I don't have much experience with it and the examples in the docs are fairly sparse.
I've already pasted one of the examples [into this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008267/vertical-alignment-of-plots-in-mathematica-via-graphicscolumn/5010829#5010829), so have a look there and see what you think!

---

Here's my attempt with `GraphicsGrid`. 
The thing that `Multipanel` lets you do but `GraphicsGrid` doesn't 
is to let you use varying Column/Row sizes.
This means that I struggled to get the arrows drawn in programmatically, and resorted to hand drawing them using the "Drawing Tools" panel ( :D )

```
With[{yslice1 = .5, yslice2 = -.8},
 GraphicsGrid[
  {{DensityPlot[Sin[15 x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     ColorFunction -> "PlumColors", AspectRatio -> 2,
     Epilog -> {Dashed, White, Line[{{-1, yslice1}, {1, yslice1}}], 
       Line[{{-1, yslice2}, {1, yslice2}}]}],
    Plot[Sin[15 x yslice1], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]},
   {SpanFromAbove,
    Plot[Sin[15 x yslice2], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
     Frame -> True]}},
  Spacings -> {Scaled[0.2], Scaled[0.0]}]]
```

[image]

---

### Edit:

Here's the same thing using `LevelScheme`, note that the frames line up.
It should be possible to add arrows - since `LevelScheme` has lots of new arrow directives -  but I'll leave that as a homework problem!

```
<< "LevelScheme`"
{yslice1 = .5, yslice2 = -.8};
Figure[{
  SetOptions[Multipanel, 
   ShowTickLabels -> {True, False, False, True}, Background -> Wheat,
   PanelLetterFontSize -> 10, Margin -> {{40, 40}, {40, 0}}],
  Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 2},
   XPlotRanges -> {-1, 1}, YPlotRanges -> {-1, 1},
   XFrameLabels -> textit["x"], YFrameLabels -> textit["y"],
   TickFontSize -> 10, XFrameTicks -> LinTicks[-1, 1, .5, 4], 
   YFrameTicks -> LinTicks[-1, 1, .5, 4],
   BufferL -> 1.5, BufferB -> 3, Order -> Vertical,
   XPanelSizes -> {1, 1}, XGapSizes -> 0.25, YGapSizes -> 0.2],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}], 
  RawGraphics[
   Plot[Sin[15 x yslice1], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}], 
  RawGraphics[
   Plot[Sin[15 x yslice2], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}, PanelAdjustments -> {{0, 0}, {0, +1.2}}],
  RawGraphics[
   DensityPlot[Sin[15 x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "PlumColors", AspectRatio -> 2],
   Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, White, 
     Line[{{-1, yslice1}, {1, yslice1}}], 
     Line[{{-1, yslice2}, {1, yslice2}}]}]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 2*72*{5, 3}
 ]
```

[image: scheming]

Comment: I just had a quick look at the matlab `subplot` syntax - it looks similar to the `levelscheme` setup... but then again both look unfamiliar to me!

Comment: that looks fantastic. Thanks for the tip on `levelscheme`. I'll check that out too.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: It's not that great - note that the frames don't line up properly because `GraphicsGrid` and friends treat a graphics object as a whole. Give me a sec and I'll post the `levelscheme` version which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: thanks Simon. I was poking around with LevelScheme and it's great. This does look much nicer than the previous one.

Comment: @d'o-o'b, LevelScheme is great for this sort of thing. One thing to pay attention to, though, is that it is very procedural, and each statement influences the ones that come after, but not before. For instance, `FigurePanel[{...}]` states that the following graphics are within that particular panel, and that stays that way until the next `FigurePanel`. Takes some time to get used to it, but you can easily craft publication quality graphics using it. Also, check out its tick marks interface, much more sane than the default.

Answer (score 4):

Re the OPs comment about GraphicsGrid, you can use FullGraphics@GraphicsGrid@{...} to get a single graphics object out.  This is necessary to get copy as PDF to work also.

Comment: +1 Never seen [FullGraphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullGraphics.html) before, despite it being "New in 2"!

Comment: I overlooked that part of the OP's question.  Good thing you picked it up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first pass at making Simon's solution dynamic.  The arrows are hard coded for this particular image.  Later I shall try to implement them more generally.

```
dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[15 x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "PlumColors", AspectRatio -> 2, PlotPoints -> 30];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  GraphicsGrid[{{dp1 ~Append~
        (Epilog -> {Dashed, White, 
         Line[{{-1, yslice1}, {1, yslice1}}], 
         Line[{{-1, yslice2}, {1, yslice2}}]}), 
     Plot[Sin[15 x yslice1], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> True]}, {SpanFromAbove, 
     Plot[Sin[15 x yslice2], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> True]}}, Spacings -> {Scaled[0.2], Scaled[0.0]}],
  Graphics[{Red, {Arrowheads[Large],
     Arrow[{{380, Rescale[yslice1, {-1, 1}, {-646, -46}]}, {440, -170}}], 
     Arrow[{{380, Rescale[yslice2, {-1, 1}, {-646, -46}]}, {440, -530}}]
     }}],
  ImageSize -> 600
 ],
 {{yslice1, 0.5, "Slice 1"}, -1, 1},
 {{yslice2, -0.8, "Slice 2"}, -1, 1}
]
```

---

Here is a slightly different method that puts the arrows inside `Epilog`, which links their position to the left plot, perhaps easier to use.

```
dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[15 x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "PlumColors", AspectRatio -> 2, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 100}, {Automatic, Automatic}}];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  GraphicsGrid[{{dp1~
      Append~(Epilog -> {{Dashed, White, 
          Line[{{-1, yslice1}, {1, yslice1}}], 
          Line[{{-1, yslice2}, {1, yslice2}}]}, {Red, 
          Arrowheads[Large],
          Arrow[{{1, yslice1}, {1.7, 0.88}}], 
          Arrow[{{1, yslice2}, {1.7, -0.9}}]
          }}), 
     Plot[Sin[15 x yslice1], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> True]}, {SpanFromAbove, 
     Plot[Sin[15 x yslice2], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> True]}}, Spacings -> {Scaled[-0.2], Scaled[0.0]}],
  ImageSize -> 600
  ],
 {{yslice1, 0.5, "Slice 1"}, -1, 1},
 {{yslice2, -0.8, "Slice 2"}, -1, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Nice. The use of `Rescale` to go between the different coords is good.